# Panel data pandas, variation according to a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stata

i am a stata user and i trying to switch to python and i having problem with some codes. If i have the following panel data

```
   id     year    quarter   fecha      jobs
     1    2007          1     220       10      
     1    2007          2     221       12    
     1    2007          3     222       12 
     1    2007          4     223       12      
     1    2008          1     224       12
     1    2008          2     225       13
     1    2008          3     226       14
     1    2008          4     227       9
     1    2009          1     228       12
     1    2009          2     229       15
     1    2009          3     230       18
     1    2009          4     231       15
     1    2010          1     232       15
     1    2010          2     233       16
     1    2010          3     234       17
     1    2010          4     235       18
     2    2007          1     220       10      
     2    2007          2     221       12    
     2    2007          3     222       12 
     2    2007          4     223       12      
     2    2008          1     224       12
     2    2008          2     225       13
     2    2008          3     226       14
     2    2008          4     227       9
     2    2009          1     228       12
     2    2009          2     229       15
     2    2009          3     230       18
     2    2009          4     231       15
     2    2010          1     232       15
     2    2010          2     233       16
     2    2010          4     235       18
```

(My panel data is much bigger than the example, is just to illustrate my problem). I want to calculate the variation of jobs of the same quarter and three year before

So result should look like these

```
   id     year    quarter   fecha      jobs   jobs_variation
     1    2007          1     220       10        Nan
     1    2007          2     221       12        Nan
     1    2007          3     222       12        Nan
     1    2007          4     223       12        Nan
     1    2008          1     224       12        Nan
     1    2008          2     225       13        Nan
     1    2008          3     226       14        Nan
     1    2008          4     227       9         Nan
     1    2009          1     228       12        Nan
     1    2009          2     229       15        Nan
     1    2009          3     230       18        Nan
     1    2009          4     231       15        Nan
     1    2010          1     232       15        0.5
     1    2010          2     233       16        0.33
     1    2010          3     234       17        0.30769
     1    2010          4     235       18        0.5
     2    2007          1     220       10        Nan
     2    2007          4     223       12        Nan
     2    2008          1     224       12        Nan
     2    2008          2     225       13        Nan
     2    2008          3     226       14        Nan
     2    2008          4     227       9         Nan
     2    2009          1     228       12        Nan
     2    2009          2     229       15        Nan
     2    2009          3     230       18        Nan
     2    2009          4     231       15        Nan
     2    2010          1     232       15        0.5
     2    2010          2     233       16        Nan
     2    2010          3     234       20        Nan
     2    2010          4     235       18        0.5
```

Check that in the second `id` year 2010 in the second and thir quarter calculation must not be me made because the id was not present at 2007Q2 and 2007Q3.

In stata the code would be,

`bys id: gen jobs_variation=jobs/jobs[_n-12]-1 if fecha[_n-12]==fecha-12`

Comment: Can you explain how you get those results please?

Comment: yes, for id 1 the calculation for jobs are ((2010Q1/2007Q1)-1), ((2010Q2/2007Q2)-1) and so on. Calculate the variation of jobs that had been from today to three years ago (in the same quarter)

Comment: See my answer, I believe it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need a `groupby` on `id` and `quarter` followed by `apply`:

```
df['jobs_variation'] = df.groupby(['id', 'quarter']).jobs\
                               .apply(lambda x: x / x.shift(3) - 1)

df

    id  year  quarter  fecha  jobs  jobs_variation
0    1  2007        1    220    10             NaN
1    1  2007        2    221    12             NaN
2    1  2007        3    222    12             NaN
3    1  2007        4    223    12             NaN
4    1  2008        1    224    12             NaN
5    1  2008        2    225    13             NaN
6    1  2008        3    226    14             NaN
7    1  2008        4    227     9             NaN
8    1  2009        1    228    12             NaN
9    1  2009        2    229    15             NaN
10   1  2009        3    230    18             NaN
11   1  2009        4    231    15             NaN
12   1  2010        1    232    15        0.500000
13   1  2010        2    233    16        0.333333
14   1  2010        3    234    17        0.416667
15   1  2010        4    235    18        0.500000
16   2  2007        1    220    10             NaN
17   2  2007        4    223    12             NaN
18   2  2008        1    224    12             NaN
19   2  2008        2    225    13             NaN
20   2  2008        3    226    14             NaN
21   2  2008        4    227     9             NaN
22   2  2009        1    228    12             NaN
23   2  2009        2    229    15             NaN
24   2  2009        3    230    18             NaN
25   2  2009        4    231    15             NaN
26   2  2010        1    232    15        0.500000
27   2  2010        2    233    16             NaN
28   2  2010        3    234    20             NaN
29   2  2010        4    235    18        0.500000
```

`x / x.shift(3)` will divide the current year's job count (for that quarter) by the corresponding value from 3 years ago.

Comment: @LucasDresl No way, did you copy it properly? Here's the single line version: `df['jobs_variation'] = df.groupby(['id', 'quarter']).jobs.apply(lambda x: x / x.shift(3) - 1)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED there is any code that could go faster?, i have 22 millions records and using grouping by function and apply takes too long

Comment: @LucasDresl Not in vanilla pandas, but you should consider looking at `dask` dataframes.